# how to detect USB insertion in imac?

Tags: objective-c, usb

how to detect USB insertion in imac using objective c? im trying to write an app running in background to detect if there is any usb being inserted to the imac. is there any code to do that in objective c?

Answer (score 2):

OS X should automatically do this for you, unless you are trying to look for something specific.  There is a file floating around the net, called "MobileDevice.h", that should give you some idea of where to start on checking if a device is inserted into USB (whether it's connected or not).

Here is a link to one place, as there are many others.

[MobileDevice.h on Pastie](http://pastie.org/pastes/1072546)

I hope this helps, as it has a USB listener, that you may be able to use.

**EDIT**

Code from Pastie:

**syslog.c**

```
#include "MobileDevice.h"
#include <assert.h>

static void cb(am_device_notification_callback_info *info, void *foo) {
    struct am_device *dev;
    CFStringRef error;
    printf("... %x\n", info->msg);
    if(info->msg == ADNCI_MSG_CONNECTED) {
        dev = info->dev;
        afc_connection *socket = NULL;
        AMDeviceConnect(dev);
        assert(AMDeviceIsPaired(dev));
        assert(AMDeviceValidatePairing(dev) == 0);
        assert(AMDeviceStartSession(dev) == 0);
        AMDeviceStartService(dev, CFSTR("com.apple.syslog_relay"), (void*)&socket, NULL);
        printf("socket=%p\n", socket);
        char c;
        while(recv((int) socket, &c, 1, 0) == 1) {
            if(c != 0)
                putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    am_device_notification *notif;
    int ret = AMDeviceNotificationSubscribe(cb, 0, 0, NULL, &notif);
    CFRunLoopRun();
}
```

**MobileDevice.h**

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   MobileDevice.h - interface to MobileDevice.framework 
 *   $LastChangedDate: 2007-07-09 18:59:29 -0700 (Mon, 09 Jul 2007) $
 *
 * Copied from http://iphonesvn.halifrag.com/svn/iPhone/
 * With modifications from Allen Porter and Scott Turner
 *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#ifndef MOBILEDEVICE_H
#define MOBILEDEVICE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if defined(WIN32)
#include <CoreFoundation.h>
typedef unsigned int mach_error_t;
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <mach/error.h>
#endif  

/* Error codes */
#define MDERR_APPLE_MOBILE  (err_system(0x3a))
#define MDERR_IPHONE        (err_sub(0))

/* Apple Mobile (AM*) errors */
#define MDERR_OK                ERR_SUCCESS
#define MDERR_SYSCALL           (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x01)
#define MDERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY     (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x03)
#define MDERR_QUERY_FAILED      (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x04) 
#define MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x0b)
#define MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x25)

/* Apple File Connection (AFC*) errors */
#define MDERR_AFC_OUT_OF_MEMORY 0x03

/* USBMux errors */
#define MDERR_USBMUX_ARG_NULL   0x16
#define MDERR_USBMUX_FAILED     0xffffffff

/* Messages passed to device notification callbacks: passed as part of
 * am_device_notification_callback_info. */
#define ADNCI_MSG_CONNECTED     1
#define ADNCI_MSG_DISCONNECTED  2
#define ADNCI_MSG_UNKNOWN       3

#define AMD_IPHONE_PRODUCT_ID   0x1290
#define AMD_IPHONE_SERIAL       "3391002d9c804d105e2c8c7d94fc35b6f3d214a3"

/* Services, found in /System/Library/Lockdown/Services.plist */
#define AMSVC_AFC                   CFSTR("com.apple.afc")
#define AMSVC_BACKUP                CFSTR("com.apple.mobilebackup")
#define AMSVC_CRASH_REPORT_COPY     CFSTR("com.apple.crashreportcopy")
#define AMSVC_DEBUG_IMAGE_MOUNT     CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.debug_image_mount")
#define AMSVC_NOTIFICATION_PROXY    CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy")
#define AMSVC_PURPLE_TEST           CFSTR("com.apple.purpletestr")
#define AMSVC_SOFTWARE_UPDATE       CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.software_update")
#define AMSVC_SYNC                  CFSTR("com.apple.mobilesync")
#define AMSVC_SCREENSHOT            CFSTR("com.apple.screenshotr")
#define AMSVC_SYSLOG_RELAY          CFSTR("com.apple.syslog_relay")
#define AMSVC_SYSTEM_PROFILER       CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.system_profiler")

typedef unsigned int afc_error_t;
typedef unsigned int usbmux_error_t;
typedef unsigned int service_conn_t;

struct am_recovery_device;

typedef struct am_device_notification_callback_info {
    struct am_device *dev;  /* 0    device */ 
    unsigned int msg;       /* 4    one of ADNCI_MSG_* */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device_notification_callback_info;

/* The type of the device restore notification callback functions.
 * TODO: change to correct type. */
typedef void (*am_restore_device_notification_callback)(struct
    am_recovery_device *);

/* This is a CoreFoundation object of class AMRecoveryModeDevice. */
typedef struct am_recovery_device {
    unsigned char unknown0[8];                          /* 0 */
    am_restore_device_notification_callback callback;   /* 8 */
    void *user_info;                                    /* 12 */
    unsigned char unknown1[12];                         /* 16 */
    unsigned int readwrite_pipe;                        /* 28 */
    unsigned char read_pipe;                            /* 32 */
    unsigned char write_ctrl_pipe;                      /* 33 */
    unsigned char read_unknown_pipe;                    /* 34 */
    unsigned char write_file_pipe;                      /* 35 */
    unsigned char write_input_pipe;                     /* 36 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_recovery_device;

/* A CoreFoundation object of class AMRestoreModeDevice. */
typedef struct am_restore_device {
    unsigned char unknown[32];
    int port;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_restore_device;

/* The type of the device notification callback function. */
typedef void(*am_device_notification_callback)(struct
    am_device_notification_callback_info *, void* arg);

/* The type of the _AMDDeviceAttached function.
 * TODO: change to correct type. */
typedef void *amd_device_attached_callback;


typedef struct am_device {
    unsigned char unknown0[16]; /* 0 - zero */
    unsigned int device_id;     /* 16 */
    unsigned int product_id;    /* 20 - set to AMD_IPHONE_PRODUCT_ID */
    char *serial;               /* 24 - set to AMD_IPHONE_SERIAL */
    unsigned int unknown1;      /* 28 */
    unsigned char unknown2[4];  /* 32 */
    unsigned int lockdown_conn; /* 36 */
    unsigned char unknown3[8];  /* 40 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device;

typedef struct am_device_notification {
    unsigned int unknown0;                      /* 0 */
    unsigned int unknown1;                      /* 4 */
    unsigned int unknown2;                      /* 8 */
    am_device_notification_callback callback;   /* 12 */ 
    unsigned int unknown3;                      /* 16 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device_notification;

typedef struct afc_connection {
    unsigned int handle;            /* 0 */
    unsigned int unknown0;          /* 4 */
    unsigned char unknown1;         /* 8 */
    unsigned char padding[3];       /* 9 */
    unsigned int unknown2;          /* 12 */
    unsigned int unknown3;          /* 16 */
    unsigned int unknown4;          /* 20 */
    unsigned int fs_block_size;     /* 24 */
    unsigned int sock_block_size;   /* 28: always 0x3c */
    unsigned int io_timeout;        /* 32: from AFCConnectionOpen, usu. 0 */
    void *afc_lock;                 /* 36 */
    unsigned int context;           /* 40 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_connection;

typedef struct afc_directory {
    unsigned char unknown[0];   /* size unknown */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_directory;

typedef struct afc_dictionary {
    unsigned char unknown[0];   /* size unknown */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_dictionary;

typedef unsigned long long afc_file_ref;

typedef struct usbmux_listener_1 {                  /* offset   value in iTunes */
    unsigned int unknown0;                  /* 0        1 */
    unsigned char *unknown1;                /* 4        ptr, maybe device? */
    amd_device_attached_callback callback;  /* 8        _AMDDeviceAttached */
    unsigned int unknown3;                  /* 12 */
    unsigned int unknown4;                  /* 16 */
    unsigned int unknown5;                  /* 20 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) usbmux_listener_1;

typedef struct usbmux_listener_2 {
    unsigned char unknown0[4144];
} __attribute__ ((packed)) usbmux_listener_2;

typedef struct am_bootloader_control_packet {
    unsigned char opcode;       /* 0 */
    unsigned char length;       /* 1 */
    unsigned char magic[2];     /* 2: 0x34, 0x12 */
    unsigned char payload[0];   /* 4 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_bootloader_control_packet;

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Public routines
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

void AMDSetLogLevel(int level);

/*  Registers a notification with the current run loop. The callback gets
 *  copied into the notification struct, as well as being registered with the
 *  current run loop. dn_unknown3 gets copied into unknown3 in the same.
 *  (Maybe dn_unknown3 is a user info parameter that gets passed as an arg to
 *  the callback?) unused0 and unused1 are both 0 when iTunes calls this.
 *  In iTunes the callback is located from $3db78e-$3dbbaf.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK            if successful
 *      MDERR_SYSCALL       if CFRunLoopAddSource() failed
 *      MDERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY if we ran out of memory
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceNotificationSubscribe(am_device_notification_callback
    callback, unsigned int unused0, unsigned int unused1, void* //unsigned int
    dn_unknown3, struct am_device_notification **notification);

/*  Connects to the iPhone. Pass in the am_device structure that the
 *  notification callback will give to you.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successfully connected
 *      MDERR_SYSCALL           if setsockopt() failed
 *      MDERR_QUERY_FAILED      if the daemon query failed
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if USBMuxConnectByPort returned 0xffffffff
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceConnect(struct am_device *device);

/*  Calls PairingRecordPath() on the given device, than tests whether the path
 *  which that function returns exists. During the initial connect, the path
 *  returned by that function is '/', and so this returns 1.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      0   if the path did not exist
 *      1   if it did
 */

int AMDeviceIsPaired(struct am_device *device);

/*  iTunes calls this function immediately after testing whether the device is
 *  paired. It creates a pairing file and establishes a Lockdown connection.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the supplied device is null
 *      MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   if the load_dict() call failed
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceValidatePairing(struct am_device *device);

/*  Creates a Lockdown session and adjusts the device structure appropriately
 *  to indicate that the session has been started. iTunes calls this function
 *  after validating pairing.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
 *      MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   if the load_dict() call failed
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceStartSession(struct am_device *device);

/* Starts a service and returns a handle that can be used in order to further
 * access the service. You should stop the session and disconnect before using
 * the service. iTunes calls this function after starting a session. It starts 
 * the service and the SSL connection. unknown may safely be
 * NULL (it is when iTunes calls this), but if it is not, then it will be
 * filled upon function exit. service_name should be one of the AMSVC_*
 * constants. If the service is AFC (AMSVC_AFC), then the handle is the handle
 * that will be used for further AFC* calls.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_SYSCALL           if the setsockopt() call failed
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceStartService(struct am_device *device, CFStringRef 
    service_name, service_conn_t *handle, unsigned int *
    unknown);

mach_error_t AMDeviceStartHouseArrestService(struct am_device *device, CFStringRef identifier, void *unknown, service_conn_t *handle, unsigned int *what);

/* Stops a session. You should do this before accessing services.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceStopSession(struct am_device *device);

/* Opens an Apple File Connection. You must start the appropriate service
 * first with AMDeviceStartService(). In iTunes, io_timeout is 0.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_AFC_OUT_OF_MEMORY if malloc() failed
 */

afc_error_t AFCConnectionOpen(service_conn_t handle, unsigned int io_timeout,
    struct afc_connection **conn);

/* Pass in a pointer to an afc_device_info structure. It will be filled. */
afc_error_t AFCDeviceInfoOpen(afc_connection *conn, struct
    afc_dictionary **info);

/* Turns debug mode on if the environment variable AFCDEBUG is set to a numeric
 * value, or if the file '/AFCDEBUG' is present and contains a value. */
void AFCPlatformInit();

/* Opens a directory on the iPhone. Pass in a pointer in dir to be filled in.
 * Note that this normally only accesses the iTunes sandbox/partition as the
 * root, which is /var/root/Media. Pathnames are specified with '/' delimiters
 * as in Unix style.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 */

afc_error_t AFCDirectoryOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path,
                             struct afc_directory **dir);

/* Acquires the next entry in a directory previously opened with
 * AFCDirectoryOpen(). When dirent is filled with a NULL value, then the end
 * of the directory has been reached. '.' and '..' will be returned as the
 * first two entries in each directory except the root; you may want to skip
 * over them.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful, even if no entries remain
 */

afc_error_t AFCDirectoryRead(afc_connection *conn/*unsigned int unused*/, struct afc_directory *dir,
    char **dirent);

afc_error_t AFCDirectoryClose(afc_connection *conn, struct afc_directory *dir);
afc_error_t AFCDirectoryCreate(afc_connection *conn, const char *dirname);
afc_error_t AFCRemovePath(afc_connection *conn, const char *dirname);
afc_error_t AFCRenamePath(afc_connection *conn, const char *from, const char *to);
afc_error_t AFCLinkPath(afc_connection *conn, long long int linktype, const char *target, const char *linkname);

/* Returns the context field of the given AFC connection. */
unsigned int AFCConnectionGetContext(afc_connection *conn);

/* Returns the fs_block_size field of the given AFC connection. */
unsigned int AFCConnectionGetFSBlockSize(afc_connection *conn);

/* Returns the io_timeout field of the given AFC connection. In iTunes this is
 * 0. */
unsigned int AFCConnectionGetIOTimeout(afc_connection *conn);

/* Returns the sock_block_size field of the given AFC connection. */
unsigned int AFCConnectionGetSocketBlockSize(afc_connection *conn);

/* Closes the given AFC connection. */
afc_error_t AFCConnectionClose(afc_connection *conn);

/* Registers for device notifications related to the restore process. unknown0
 * is zero when iTunes calls this. In iTunes,
 * the callbacks are located at:
 *      1: $3ac68e-$3ac6b1, calls $3ac542(unknown1, arg, 0)
 *      2: $3ac66a-$3ac68d, calls $3ac542(unknown1, 0, arg)
 *      3: $3ac762-$3ac785, calls $3ac6b2(unknown1, arg, 0)
 *      4: $3ac73e-$3ac761, calls $3ac6b2(unknown1, 0, arg)
 */

unsigned int AMRestoreRegisterForDeviceNotifications(
    am_restore_device_notification_callback dfu_connect_callback,
    am_restore_device_notification_callback recovery_connect_callback,
    am_restore_device_notification_callback dfu_disconnect_callback,
    am_restore_device_notification_callback recovery_disconnect_callback,
    unsigned int unknown0,
    void *user_info);

/* Causes the restore functions to spit out (unhelpful) progress messages to
 * the file specified by the given path. iTunes always calls this right before
 * restoring with a path of
 * "$HOME/Library/Logs/iPhone Updater Logs/iPhoneUpdater X.log", where X is an
 * unused number.
 */

unsigned int AMRestoreEnableFileLogging(char *path);

/* Initializes a new option dictionary to default values. Pass the constant
 * kCFAllocatorDefault as the allocator. The option dictionary looks as
 * follows:
 * {
 *      NORImageType => 'production',
 *      AutoBootDelay => 0,
 *      KernelCacheType => 'Release',
 *      UpdateBaseband => true,
 *      DFUFileType => 'RELEASE',
 *      SystemImageType => 'User',
 *      CreateFilesystemPartitions => true,
 *      FlashNOR => true,
 *      RestoreBootArgs => 'rd=md0 nand-enable-reformat=1 -progress'
 *      BootImageType => 'User'
 *  }
 *
 * Returns:
 *      the option dictionary   if successful
 *      NULL                    if out of memory
 */ 

CFMutableDictionaryRef AMRestoreCreateDefaultOptions(CFAllocatorRef allocator);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Less-documented public routines
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* mode 2 = read, mode 3 = write */
afc_error_t AFCFileRefOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path,
    unsigned long long mode, afc_file_ref *ref);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefSeek(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
    unsigned long long offset1, unsigned long long offset2);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefRead(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
    void *buf, unsigned int *len);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefSetFileSize(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
    unsigned long long offset);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefWrite(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
    const void *buf, unsigned int len);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefClose(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref);

afc_error_t AFCFileInfoOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path, struct
    afc_dictionary **info);
afc_error_t AFCKeyValueRead(struct afc_dictionary *dict, char **key, char **
    val);
afc_error_t AFCKeyValueClose(struct afc_dictionary *dict);

unsigned int AMRestorePerformRecoveryModeRestore(struct am_recovery_device *
    rdev, CFDictionaryRef opts, void *callback, void *user_info);
unsigned int AMRestorePerformRestoreModeRestore(struct am_restore_device *
    rdev, CFDictionaryRef opts, void *callback, void *user_info);

struct am_restore_device *AMRestoreModeDeviceCreate(unsigned int unknown0,
    unsigned int connection_id, unsigned int unknown1);

unsigned int AMRestoreCreatePathsForBundle(CFStringRef restore_bundle_path,
    CFStringRef kernel_cache_type, CFStringRef boot_image_type, unsigned int
    unknown0, CFStringRef *firmware_dir_path, CFStringRef *
    kernelcache_restore_path, unsigned int unknown1, CFStringRef *
    ramdisk_path);

unsigned int AMDeviceGetConnectionID(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceEnterRecovery(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceDisconnect(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceRetain(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceRelease(struct am_device *device);
CFStringRef AMDeviceCopyValue(struct am_device *device, unsigned int, CFStringRef cfstring);
CFStringRef AMDeviceCopyDeviceIdentifier(struct am_device *device);

typedef void (*notify_callback)(CFStringRef notification, void *data);

mach_error_t AMDPostNotification(service_conn_t socket, CFStringRef  notification, CFStringRef userinfo);
mach_error_t AMDObserveNotification(void *socket, CFStringRef notification);
mach_error_t AMDListenForNotifications(void *socket, notify_callback cb, void *data);
mach_error_t AMDShutdownNotificationProxy(void *socket);

/*edits by geohot*/
mach_error_t AMDeviceDeactivate(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceActivate(struct am_device *device, CFMutableDictionaryRef);
/*end*/

void *AMDeviceSerialize(struct am_device *device);
void AMDAddLogFileDescriptor(int fd);
kern_return_t AMDeviceSendMessage(service_conn_t socket, void *unused, CFPropertyListRef plist);
kern_return_t AMDeviceReceiveMessage(service_conn_t socket, CFDictionaryRef options, CFPropertyListRef * result);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Semi-private routines
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/*  Pass in a usbmux_listener_1 structure and a usbmux_listener_2 structure
 *  pointer, which will be filled with the resulting usbmux_listener_2.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if completed successfully
 *      MDERR_USBMUX_ARG_NULL   if one of the arguments was NULL
 *      MDERR_USBMUX_FAILED     if the listener was not created successfully
 */

usbmux_error_t USBMuxListenerCreate(struct usbmux_listener_1 *esi_fp8, struct
    usbmux_listener_2 **eax_fp12);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Less-documented semi-private routines
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

usbmux_error_t USBMuxListenerHandleData(void *);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Private routines - here be dragons
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* AMRestorePerformRestoreModeRestore() calls this function with a dictionary
 * in order to perform certain special restore operations
 * (RESTORED_OPERATION_*). It is thought that this function might enable
 * significant access to the phone. */

typedef unsigned int (*t_performOperation)(struct am_restore_device *rdev,
    CFDictionaryRef op); // __attribute__ ((regparm(2)));

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```